# Adding NULL to an integer to get the integer result in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-function

I have say a table, the **columns** of which will contain **integer** value but i am not sure if they **may contain NULL** too. Now lets say I want to **add the integers**, **(along with any NULL)** to get the **result** as an **integer** even when any column in between is NULL.

I am **aware** of the **ISNULL()** function and **COALESCE()** function. But i would prefer not to use any of these. **Nor** i want to use **CASE**. I know that **CASE** would do what i want, but I am looking for something more better.

Just like we have **CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL** to ensure that when a string is concatenated to a null value, the result is not null.

I want something similar to this option. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you don't want to use the functions that are designed for this problem?

Comment: May I ask what the reason for you is, not to use isnull as it's made for what you want to do?

Comment: `ISNULL()` and `COALESCE()` are designed for doing what you need to do. How do you intend to beat that?

Comment: Every other solution would just be a hack, why not just use those functions?

Comment: I know that isull and coalesce would do this. But i was asking if there's any other way!!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just use those functions. Assuming you can't:

```
SELECT SUM(MyIntCol) --filters out NULLs automatically

SELECT CASE WHEN MyIntCol IS NOT NULL THEN MyIntCol ELSE 0 END --default value 0
```

Comment: But, i guess there's a problem. I want to add the values which are in different columns.

Comment: You can use the second code line I posted for that.

Comment: But, i thought that I mentioned not to use CASE even. Anyways, thanks for telling that sum() would ignore nulls...

Comment: OK, I did not see that. Your question has no answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to you but it might be a solution for people running `MS SQL Server 2012` or newer.

```
SELECT IIF(<NullableColumn1> is null, 0, <NullableColumn1>)
+ IIF(<NullableColumn2> is null, 0, <NullableColumn12) ...
FROM <YourTable>
```

But I assume, that the engine will do the same what is done, when there is `CASE` used instead.

Comment: Btw. `IIF` is indeed translated into case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: @usr actually this was not my intention. I just wanted to know if there's any other way except for those i have mentioned.